# XSLT for each loop with an if else

Tags: xslt

This is for a university purpose. My xslt is not working. I'm trying to do a for-each with and if statement. I try it with the = or != it doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
(Sorry the indentation is bad).

```
<xsl:for-each select="$rankingItems/userDefinedVectorLine[userDefinedField/fieldLabel='LIST' 
and (userDefinedField[fieldLabel='COUP'] or userDefinedField[fieldLabel='PAY']) ]" >
<xsl:variable name="date" select="userDefinedField[fieldLabel='LIST']/fieldValue"/>
<xsl:variable name="Tempo" select="userDefinedField[2]/fieldLabel"/>
<xsl:if  test="$Tempo!='COUP'" >
    <xsl:variable name="coupon" select="'TITI'" />
</xsl:if> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$coupon"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: If you can share the input XML and the expected output, it will be easier to understand what is not working in the XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `coupon` variable exists only inside the `xsl:if` block.
So when you try to use it (outside of the `xsl:if` block) you get an empty value.

Probably you should create this variable "unconditionally", but its **content**
should be created based on a condition, e.g.:

```
<xsl:variable name="coupon" select="if ($Tempo!='COUP') then 'TITI' else ''" />
```

One more question: Is it your intention that `coupon` variable
contained *'TITI'* (a **constant string**)?
Or maybe its value should be the content of `TITI` (child) **element**?

If the second is true, then write just `TITI` without surrounding apostrophes.

And the last remark: Asking a question provide also the source XML code.